# get address parts based on requested parts

Tags: javascript, strings, typescript

I have different format of address in an array, those format looks like this

`lastname/firstname/_/country/postalCode/_/regionId/city/addressFirst/addressSecond/_/phone`

`lastname` => a part of the address (noted `AddressPart`)
`/` => a separation
`_` => a line break

the above entire would do

```
lastname firstname
country postalCode
regionId city addressFirst addressSecond
phone
```

now, I have a method, where I basically want to pass a parameter what part I am interested in, and get the resulting format:

f.e

```
 input : ["country", "postalCode"]
 return "country/postalCode

 input : ["lastname", "firstname", "regionId"]
 return "lastname/firstname/_/regionId"

 input : ["firstname", "country", "regionId", "city"]
 return "firstname/_/country/_/regionId/city"

 input : ["country", "regionId", "phone"]
 return "country/_/regionId/_/phone"
```

Here is the method :

```
  type AddressPart = "firstname" | "lastname" | ... | "phone";
  const allAddressParts = ["firstname", "lastname", ... ,"phone"];

  static getLocaleAddress(
    parts: AddressPart[]
  ) {
    let addressFormat = `lastname/firstname/_/country/postalCode/_/regionId/city/addressFirst/addressSecond/_/phone`;
    // (1)
    const toRemove = allAddressParts.filter((part) => !parts.includes(part));
    // (2)
    toRemove.forEach((part) => {
      addressFormat = addressFormat
        .replace(`_/${part}/_`, '_')
        .replace(new RegExp(part + '/?'), '')
        .replace(/^(_\/)+/, '')
        .replace(/\/(_\/)*$/, '');
    });
    return addressFormat.split('/');
  }
```

What I don't like in what I did is :

1. I replace items, so I need to filter from the list of parts the one I want, to keep the one I want to remove
2. it is 4 replaces operations, and I was wondering if it was improvable.

Thanks for the tips :x

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't like in what I did is :
>
> 1. I replace items, so I need to filter from the list of parts the one I want, to keep the one I want to remove
> 2. it is 4 replaces operations, and I was wondering if it was improvable.

---

It is possible to avoid replacing items. For example,

```
'use strict';

function getLocaleAddress(parts) {
    // field and line separators
    const fieldSep = "/";
    const lineBreak = "_";

    // address parts plus lineBreak as set
    parts = new Set(parts).add(lineBreak);

    // format template as array
    const format = (
       "lastname/firstname/_/" +
        "country/postalCode/_/" +
        "regionId/city/addressFirst/addressSecond/_/" +
        "phone"        
        )
        .split(fieldSep)
    ;

    // selected address parts as array
    let selected = [];
    let inLine = false;
    for (const field of format) {
        if (parts.has(field)) {
            if (field !== lineBreak) {
                inLine = true;
            }
            if (inLine) {
                selected.push(field);
            }
        }
        if (field === lineBreak) {
            inLine = false;
        }
    }
    const end = selected.length - 1;
    if (end >= 0 && selected[end] === lineBreak) {
        selected.pop();
    }
    return selected;
}
```

---

```
function test(input) {
    const fieldSep = "/";
    console.log(
        "\n", input, 
        "\n", getLocaleAddress(input).join(fieldSep)
    );
}

test(["country", "postalCode"]);
test(["lastname", "firstname", "regionId"]);
test(["firstname", "country", "regionId", "city"]);
test(["country", "regionId", "phone"]);
```

---

```
$ node cr.address.js

 [ 'country', 'postalCode' ] 
 country/postalCode

 [ 'lastname', 'firstname', 'regionId' ] 
 lastname/firstname/_/regionId

 [ 'firstname', 'country', 'regionId', 'city' ] 
 firstname/_/country/_/regionId/city

 [ 'country', 'regionId', 'phone' ] 
 country/_/regionId/_/phone

$
```

---

I used [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/) and your test cases to compare my code to your code. My code was fastest. Your code was 70.3% slower.